# I centered an element in a column in bootstrap grid with <center>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for tell this in Stackoverflow. I have sinned. Sorry but I cannot get an element centered and the  tag makes everything work like a charm. As you can guess I am not very fluent in CSS. Can anyone see a better way to do it?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"><img alt="Logo" src="./images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <center><span> text to center</span></center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <span element></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: And *this* (`.col-lg-8 {text-align: center;}`) didn't work?

Comment: @DavidLee Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I do not want that. I want *just this one* not *all* col-lg-8

Comment: Then apply a custom class to that element specifically - it's still a much better alternative to using a deprecated tag.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError can you try to give me an example. Like (.col-lg-8 .customClass {text-align: center;}) ???

Comment: Sure, refer to this fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/o4dzsc0k/2/ demonstrating methods to horizontally align text center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has its own "text-center" class. If you apply it to your .col-lg-8 tag, it would allow you to remove that center tag.

It would look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2"><img alt="Logo" src="./images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
            <span> text to center</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <span element></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Juanjo, you're welcome. Also, you might want to checkout the documentation of bootstrap, since there are a lot of "helper classes" like this one. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes

Comment: Thanks @KarulessWhisper Just out of curiosity do you know the equivalent with react-bootstrap? If not I will have to just render the plain HTML that is not a big deal.. Thanks again. Very very useful. I would give you more upvotes if I could.

Comment: @Juanjo, unfortunately I don't.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering we use the className:

`<Col lg={8} className="text-center">`